# Chosen jquery - List is not loading in modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

In rails 4.2.2, I am using `chosen` jquery plugin for dropdown(multiple) field inside a `modal` form. Right now form & field is loading with no errors but collection(list) is not loading, if I try to search then it shows "No results...".

In controller,

```
@users = User.all.collect(&:name)
```

In views,

```
<%= f.input :users, :as =>:select, :label=>false, :collection =>[], :input_html=>{:multiple=>true, :class=>"form-control"} %>
```

In view.js.erb

```
var content = "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>"form")) %>";
var container = $('#main-lightbox-container');
container.find('.modal-content').html(content);
container.modal({});

initializeMultipleChoose("#event_users", JSON.parse('<%= raw(@users) %>'), {width: "95%", max_selected_options: 5, allow_single_deselect: true});
$("#event_users").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

In custom .js file,

```
function initializeMultipleChoose(id, selectedOptions, parameters){
  selectedOptionsArray = $.isArray(selectedOptions) ? selectedOptions : [selectedOptions]
  object = $(id);
  $.each(object.find("option"), function(key, content){
    option = object.find(content);
    if(selectedOptionsArray.indexOf(option.val())> -1)
        option.attr('selected',true);
  })
  object.chosen(parameters);
}
```

What I need to do for loading a list? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that you are trying to init the chosen plugin BEFORE the HTML DOM is available? Could you check?